# Element should have been "select" but was "span" in selenium

Tags: selenium

Toggle button is present in an web application similar to

```
http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=on-off-switch
```

Search for "option two" in the above link.

Html code of the button is like this when turned Off

```
    <div class="field-block button-height">
                <label style="width:175px" class="label" for="input-2"><b>Case Association</b><sup>*</sup>
                <span id="reqCaseAssociationTD" style="display: none;">
                        required</span>
                </label>
                <p style="margin:0px" class="field switch">


                        <label style="margin:0 0 4px" class="cb-enable"><span>On</span></label>
                        <label style="margin:0 0 4px" class="cb-disable selected"><span>Off</span></label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="caseAssociation">

                </p>
                <span style="margin-top:8px;margin-left:2px" data-tooltip="Simulataneous post from the same user (Twitter and Facebook) would get associated with the previous open case of the user." class="helpText showToolTip"></span>
            </div>
```

Html code of the button is like this when turned ON

```
    <div class="field-block button-height">
                <label style="width:175px" class="label" for="input-2"><b>Case Association</b><sup>*</sup>
                <span id="reqCaseAssociationTD" style="display: none;">
                        required</span>
                </label>
                <p style="margin:0px" class="field switch">


                        <label style="margin:0 0 4px" class="cb-enable selected"><span>On</span></label>
                        <label style="margin:0 0 4px" class="cb-disable"><span>Off</span></label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="caseAssociation" checked="checked">

                </p>
                <span style="margin-top:8px;margin-left:2px" data-tooltip="Simulataneous post from the same user (Twitter and Facebook) would get associated with the previous open case of the user." class="helpText showToolTip"></span>
            </div>
```

Used the following identifiers

```
    //Case Association Turned On
    @FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "a.cb-enable.selected"))
    public List<WebElement> caseAssociationIsON;

    //Case Association Turned OFF
    @FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "a.cb-disable.selected"))
    public List<WebElement> caseAssociationIsOFF;
```

While running using the selenium getting the error

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element
>   should have been "select" but was "span"

How do fix this. If more details are needed, please suggest.

Comment: @lauda after changing to this element is getting identified correctly and being clicked. after clicking this figured out that i'm looking at the wrong element. Great this worked

Comment: Nice, added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any element that would match your selector, you should use `label` instead of `a`, like:

`label.cb-enable.selected`

and

`label.cb-disable.selected`

or use a selector based on input. a means link and you don't have any.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still have the error what happens is that you must add an specific route:

In my case:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NibXa.png)

This is the resultant code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q17zM.png)

Comment: Please post your codes directly instead of one image link.